# What is the average acquisition cost of a Facebook "Like"?

Tags: facebook, advertising

Suppose you want to invest in a Facebook ad, targeted to a specific audience, how many $ would I need to spend to get one "Like" in my Facebook fan page?

Note: I know not all users, industries, ads, landing pages, are the same, I am just looking for an average of past benchmarks on a $ per Like basis.

Comment: Related: How to get more Likes on Facebook by Oatmeal - http://theoatmeal.com/comics/facebook_likes

Answer (score 2):

Here are two resources going over both the cost, and CPA of gaining fans and what companies are paying

Facebook Ads versus Google Ads | A benchmark analysis
http://www.adworkz.com/blog/facebook-google-benchmarks/

Pay Per Fan: What Big Brands Are Paying For Facebook Fans
http://www.searchenginejournal.com/pay-per-fan-what-big-brands-are-paying-for-facebook-fans/23791/

excerpt from above

> The value of these fans depends on how much money you make from them
>   down the road. On Facebook, if you don’t engage them, you’ll probably
>   lose them. You have to court them – but that’s page management or
>   community management, and beyond the focus of this article. So one
>   determinant of cost per fan price are questions like:
>
> - What’s your conversion rate from fan to customer?
> - What’s your average sale?
> - What’s the lifetime value of these customers?

Answer (score 0):

This is a hard question to answer because the number one problem with marketing is that you do not know if the user landed there 'naturally' or through an ad. I would say that you should put a starting low ball amount of money into a facebook ad and then go from there. From there you will be able to see the correlation of money to likes.

Comment: Surely you can see the referring site and if it's "facebook.com" then you know they came from facebook?

Answer (score 0):

You can get about 200 - 500 likes for $5 on the $5 job sites.

Comment: are you implying any particular website? :)

Comment: @Chrys google micro jobs site, I've used jobsfor10.com in the past.

Comment: just search 'buy facebook like' or 'buy facebook followers'

Answer (score 0):

I have seen mine change drastically. I set new parameters and, every time I did that, the cost per page like seemed to increase. This tells me that my original sample was probably much closer to the type of viewer I should be targeting than what I am now. My average cost per page like has increased from .08 to .48 cents.

Some of this has to do with the click through rate, which mine appears to have remained pretty constant despite the changes that I have made. I'm a bit baffled by this last increase. I had previously only seen .12 cents per page like, and suddenly it went through the roof. I personally don't see a viable reason for this other than that fewer people may be surfing today due to holiday travels.